# Repository pattern in .net C#, problem with returning customized error

Tags: c#, .net, repository-pattern

So it's new to me and I have a certain problem. I'm using repository pattern, so the functions in the controller call the matching functions in the service class.

But the function in service checks for different issues, like an account was not found, then returns null. Then, if the account was found, but the money is insufficient, I return null as well (I have no choice).

Now, the caller function in the controller cannot know which problem caused the function to return null, therefore, I can return BadRequest but with no spesific error string.

I thought about returning a custom object of a custon class, that holds information about the error and the class itself to return, but it sound a bad practice to me.

Another option is to use try-catch.

What is recommended to do in that case?

Thank you

Comment: Usually, we handle these cases with some custom exception and the other exceptions derived from this exception and then a middleware catches these exceptions and modifies the response accordingly.

Comment: So I should throw custom exception in the service for each problem, rather then returning null? and then catch each spesific exception in the controller, and then modify the response accordingly?

Comment: Well, throwing is better IMHO, a null value can not mean anything. Catching exceptions in the control would cause  many duplicate try-catch blocks so it would be better handling it in the middleware.

Comment: Completely agree with @Eldar. This behaviour should ideally not be handled by the controller or repository. This way you can implement this behaviour in all controllers/repositories without having to type the same code 500 times

Comment: @Eldar Thank you, could you explain what would be the middleware in my case?